# Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type

Tags: google-earth-engine, java, value-extraction

I'm trying to extract the pixel value of the first image of the Modis Aqua chlor_a product but when applying the code I used to do this with the Landsat dataset I'm having an error : Error in map(ID=A2013094):
Array: No numbers in 'values', must provide a type.
I tried to filter by ID but there's a lot of them. Is there a way to filter all the null values or to avoid this problem ?
Here's the code I use :

```
var Modis = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI')
    .filterDate('2013-04-01', '2018-04-01')
    .filterBounds(ROI)
    
var Modis_chloa = Modis.select("chlor_a").sort('system:time_start')

var ModisProjection = Modis.first().projection()


var valuesByBandM = Modis_chloa.first()
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : ROI,
    crs : ModisProjection});

var firstFeaturesM = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.Array(valuesByBandM.values())
    .transpose()
    .toList()
    .map(function (values) {
      return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
        valuesByBandM.keys(), 
        values
      ))
    })
)
print(firstFeaturesM)

function valuesByBandsMfunction(img){
  var valuesByBand = img
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(),
    geometry : ROI, 
    crs : ModisProjection})
   var features = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.Array(valuesByBand.values())
    .transpose()
    .toList()
    .map(function (values) {
      return ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary.fromLists(
        valuesByBand.keys(), 
        values
      ))
    })
    )
     var SumFeaturesM = firstFeaturesM.merge(features)
    return SumFeaturesM
}
var chloa_Modis = Modis_chloa.map(valuesByBandsMfunction).flatten()
print(chloa_Modis)
```

You can find it there : https://code.earthengine.google.com/2ad778ebe2c50c4c2fdf8da72489aa3a

Answer (score 0):

How about using a filter based on the mask of the image within your ROI?

```js
function maskInRoi(img){
  return img.set({
    "mask": img.rename("mask").mask().reduceRegion({
      reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry:ROI,
      crs:ModisProjection
    }).get("mask") 
  })
}
Modis_chloa = Modis_chloa.map(maskInRoi).filter(ee.Filter.gt("mask",0.1))
```

Given your ROI is really small, some pesky images will pass the filter above (if you use `.gt("mask",0)` ) even if a fraction of a pixel touches your ROI, e.g. 2013299:

[image]

and then you will still get the original error because your valuesByBandM returns an empty dictionary. Therefore, I suggest using a higher threshold (e.g. I used 0.1 above).

https://code.earthengine.google.com/044b77eeeb824aca5a41f9ddca89e7ab

Comment: Thanks that's very helpfull, when trying to apply the same filter to the Landsat dataset I got this error : Collection.first: Error in map(ID=LC08_171066_20130426):
Image.rename: The number of names (1) must match the number of bands (19).
Do you know if there is a way to apply this filter to multiple band or it's impossible ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that I think does what you want to achieve.. but much simpler:

```js
function getArray(img){
var dict = img
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer : ee.Reducer.toList(), 
    geometry : ROI,
    crs : ModisProjection
  })
var chlor_a = ee.List(dict.get("chlor_a"))

return ee.Feature(null, {
  "chlor_a":chlor_a,
  "date": img.date(),
  "N_chlor_a": chlor_a.length()
})
}
```

then you can filter by `N_chlor_a>0` You could also add other bands easily.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9b9505d5df8fa444892728f3835923b7